# maping a texture onto a icosaeder

Tags: cinema4d

I want to create a [dymaxion projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dymaxion_map) onto a icosaeder in cinema4d.

But it's hard. The end result would be an object like this:

[image]

But how the heck would the texture look for this thing?

When doing this icosaeder with classic paper and glue the texture looks like this:

[image]

But for a 3d Object that is totally wrong.

- How would I have to arrange the texture?
- What Mapping projection would be the correct one?

[image]

(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: You'd have to manually unwrap the UV Layout otherwise it won't work.

Comment: It works exaclty like paper except that you need to do the unwrapping. (so in essence you do exactly teh same thing in reverse.)